# LDAP path to be declared

Tags: ldap

I have ldap domain at pa-qa.pa.myserver.com. I am little confused how I can give LDAP path in the code.

For an example I have other domain name as pa.myserver.com and I gave LDAP path as

```
LDAP://pa.myserver.com/OU=members,DC=pa,DC=myserver,DC=com.
```

How can I declare for the former one. I tried multiple ways but every time I was getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're looking for, but there's a chance you mean this: turn `pa-qa.pa.myserver.com` into a valid LDAP path.

Since I don't know your network, I don't know whether `pa-qa` really is a server .... but there's a chance you could get your LDAP path by just "splitting" up your DNS-style server name into parts, and prefixing each one of the with a `DC=` (DC stands for Domain Component) - so your resulting LDAP path could be something like:

```
LDAP://pa-qa.pa.myserver.com/OU=members,DC=pa-qa,DC=pa,DC=myserver,DC=com
```

But again: that really depends on your network and its setup, and it's really not possible to say for sure just from your DNS machine name..... (that machine could be part of the `DC=pa,DC=Myserver,DC=Com` domain, too).